# my air handler closet is heating up the room behind it in the summer when AC runs the most

Tags: closet, air

My air handler closet gets hot in the summer.  Likely because that’s when it runs the most or because it vents to attic and attic heat is coming in.  Problem is that it heats up the room behind it.   How can I keep the heat from heating up the room behind the closet? Add foil or wool insulation boards?

Comment: What are the walls made of?

Comment: there should not be heat in air handler! it sucks air from the rooms (return vents) not from attic, and blows it back cooled over the coil. In this close loop system there are not vents to the outside

Comment: Yes, there's no heat in the air handler! There a few hundred watts of heat being made by the blower motor, but that goes into the flow air and is immediately chilled by the A/C coils.  The heat is coming through from the attic due to faulty insulation.

Comment: How is it heating the next room?  Through the wall?  The wall is becoming hot enough to be noticeable in the next room?   What is the wall's construction?  Studs and drywall? Is there drywall on the closet side?  Is it possible to close the opening to the attic?  Any reason you shouldn't?  Does the air handler include gas heating or is it just an air handler?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the terminology is wrong,

there should be no heat been sucked from the attic into your home.

Usually the fans in attic is there to exaust the attic heat to the outside, not in to you home.

If you are calling

> air handler closet

That is usually a part of your AC. It has a fan and heat exchange coil. That one should newer see any air from outside your home and specially not from attic.

It draws the air from the rooms trough air returns opening (large opening like 20x20 inches) in one or more places, and they have dust filters in them, then the fan blows the cold air back in to the rooms.

Sometimes you will have air ducts distribution on the attic, but those need to be well isolated. For that you need to go to the attic and close (seal) all the ducts outlets so no air can come in from the attic. The air handler closet temperature should be +/- room temperature. In any case check and clean or replace the air return filters.